# Can't move jQuery to footer

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, optimization, wp-register-script

Below two methods did not help me. My jQuery is always on the head section. What can be the reason?

**Method 1: (adding below code to function.php)**

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js',array(),'1.9.0',true);

}
```

this one works when I change `'jquery'`, to some other string as first parameter in `wp_enqueue_script`. So why it doesn't work with jquery handle?

**Method 2: (adding below code to function.php)**

```
function pwcc_jquery_to_footer( &$wp_scripts ) {
      if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
      }
      $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery',         'group', 1 ); 
      $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery-core',    'group', 1 ); 
      $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery-migrate', 'group', 1 ); 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'pwcc_jquery_to_footer' );
```

This code did not have any affect on the page, it modifies `group` which tells wheather the script should be in header or footer

Comment: Although it's not a good idea to do this (since a badly written code in your theme might break), but have you tried the usual _"disabling plugins and switching to default theme"_ procedure?

Comment: @JackJohansson no haven't tried yet, the theme is my own and I use live environment only it would be hard to do, actually one method worked, which is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21167716/1235655, but I don't know how healthy is this.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a good practice. You are forcing every script to be loaded in the footer, which is not really recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best way but removing the default WordPress actions that allow any scripts in the document's head can help:

```
function md_footer_enqueue_scripts() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'md_footer_enqueue_scripts');`
```